# SQL Server random timeout issue

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel

**Hello SO**,

I am currently attempting to run a stored procedure that processes apx ~50k records. It sorts the records into different tables, deletes some records, etc.

However, a relatively long prepared statement will always result in the following error(s):

```
> [2016-12-08 19:28:24] local.INFO: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]:
> General error: 20003 Adaptive Server connection timed out [20003]
> (severity 6) [(null)] in
> /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:479
> Stack trace:
> #0 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(479):
> PDOStatement->execute()
> #1 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(762):
> Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Database\SqlServerConnection),
> 'EXEC dbo.cleanD...', Array)
> #2 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(725):
> Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('EXEC dbo.cleanD...',
> Array, Object(Closure))
> #3 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(480):
> Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('EXEC dbo.cleanD...', Array,
> Object(Closure))
> #4 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php(317):
> Illuminate\Database\Connection->statement('EXEC dbo.cleanD...')
> #5 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(237):
> Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->__call('statement', Array)
```

What gets me is that, through the use of laravel chunk, I am able to insert  ~50k records without incident:

```
$data = $data->chunk(500);

foreach ($data as $rows) {
    Log::info("INSERT START: " . date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'));
    DB::table("the.db")->insert($rows->toArray());
}
```

But as soon as the stored procedure runs (which could take ~2-4 minutes)

I get the above error. I've tried a ton of different solutions, including breaking the stored procedure into littler ones, but still I get the error.

Always the same error:

```
General error: 20003 Adaptive Server connection timed out [20003] (severity 6) [(null)] in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:479
```

I have a sneaking suspicion that somewhere (in laravel? php.ini?) that I might have to up a timeout limit for the **database**

Any thing helps, thanks in advance!

Comment: Any chance of breaking the query down into several smaller queries? Also, could you use a SQL Server Job?

Comment: I did, unfortunately the script that takes the most amount of time needs to stay all together

Comment: Might be worth looking into making it a Job if possible, especially if it's run on a fixed schedule.

Comment: It's a once a month upload of a huge excel sheet that gets processed, I am probably going to redo the logic (I just started here) the person before me did all the "business logic" in the database

Comment: Yeah, I'd definitely recommend that once you have time - databases are usually really fast for data processing type tasks and really slow for business logic (plus obviously it's better architecture to separate them, you don't want business logic in your database layer for the same reason it shouldn't be in the UI).

Comment: @EJoshuaS for sure, I plan on moving it away from mssql too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't verify this works but I seen in another question you use the option `PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT` to forcefully set a higher timeout on it.  I'm not sure what the default would be.

```
'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
    'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'prefix'   => '',
    'options' => [
        PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 240  // 240 seconds.
    ]
],
```

You may also want to take a look at [Can I set a query timeout when using Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mssql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601140/can-i-set-a-query-timeout-when-using-zend-db-adapter-pdo-mssql).

Comment: Thanks, gonna try that right now and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a bunch. So obscure, that post (where you got the fix from) isn't even the same error code, but it works! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solution that @user3158900 offered, I know I mentioned this in the comments but just to reiterate them here (since comments may be deleted), you might want to consider using a [SQL Server Job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187880.aspx) if the query can't be broken down more. Jobs can do all kinds of things (integration packages, command line applications, scripts, etc.) in addition to running SQL scripts, so they're great for automating routine administrative-type tasks.

If you're moving away from SQL Server, Oracle has a [job scheduler](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse.htm#i1033533) too, but I'm not as familiar with it.

Since you indicated that you're planning to move the logic out of SQL Server at some point, once you have time one possibility (if you happen to be using a Windows server, which I highly recommend since I own Microsoft stock :)) is to write a console application and use the [Windows Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx) to run it on your chosen schedule. You can even have it run in the background without opening a console window.

Comment: Thanks - it would have been super helpful if mssql had a "fire and forget" option for a stored procedure (without having to set up a separate table w/ triggers etc)